# Android Rebuild (APK Tools or APK Editor Studio) Not updating version number from manifest or updating the images

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got an apk my friend made (non play store) hes given me the all clear to mess around with it for personal use, I have decompiled it in the APK Editor Studio and updated the app logo which is working. However when I update the images used in assets eg > =@mipmap/ic_launcher the pngs dont update in the app, ie when I update a small image used in one of the menus it is still picking up an old image which is no longer there. The manifesto version number doesnt show as the new value (+1) when I compile sign and launch the app it still says 90 when I updated it to 91.

Newbie here just getting into it so please keep it simple to start with. I am hoping to get a fell for how it all hangs together before trying to make my own project in android studio.

Comment: Hi @Joe Harrison, create your own project by viewing sample projects provided by your friends. Make it from 0 so you can understand the process.

Comment: You're doing it the other way around, usually you start with a simple hello world project learn the folder structure, managing assets, styling, obfuscation,  base components of an android application the bare bone basics. Tools like apk studio are just tools to manipulate assets in an apk if you don't have the source code

Comment: @JimmyFlash I know but I would like to finish this bit off before I start my own, do you know why assets arent updating in the new build